# What are the use cases of an in-memory database?

Tags: sql, database, persistence, hsqldb

I'm looking into HSQLDB, and it appears that it stores tables in memory unless you specify otherwise. This sounds like a horrible idea to me, but evidently it's not as people use this database quite a bit.

If you store your database data in-memory, what happens if your application process dies? How on earth could you hope to have the same database when you launch your application again?

Databases are for persistent data, so why would you want to store an entire database in volatile memory instead of persisting on the filesystem? Is there a use case for such a database I'm missing here?

Comment: what do you think memcached is? an in-memory database... you wouldn't store a bank database in a ram-only DB, but you could use that ram-only db as a fast cache.

Comment: You would use it when persistent storage IO is extremely expensive. Imagine a sensor of some kind that has to send data to a satellite. Or expendable electronics such as a missile or a busy webserver running MINIX 3 ;) In any case you can always flush to storage once in a while.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way it works, I believe, is there is a completely separate process, either a daemon or service depending on your OS, that is the database.

This process is in charge of the database, which most likely gets 'backed up' onto your hard drive at specific intervals. The process also handles requests for data from other processes, ie, your application.

Having the database cached in memory is much, much faster than having it be read from a file when every request is made. (look up read/write times for hard drives and memory, if you doubt it)

Comment: Oh ok, I wasn't aware of the periodic caching to disk. Yeah I can definitely understand the desirability from a performance standpoint. One more question: How do such databases generally handle recovering data from the cached stuff on disk? It seems like if you're caching periodically, there will always be a bit of data loss on a restore, because of the time between the crash and the last cache to disk

Comment: @dsw88 I dont know just how often it writes the changes to disk, it could do it immediately after receiving the querys. And there would only be a couple reasons to why the database would have to stop running, most often I would guess is a server restart. But the program gets a notification (or some other way to know its shutting down), and has a chance to write to disk. The entire server could crash and go down, which is unlikely, but would probably result in data loss.